# Potential scam on Coinw6 exchange

Tags: scam

Has anyone had their funds froze by Coinw6 claiming money laundering asking for you to make a deposit into a specific blockchain account to verify you are not laundering money?[image]

Answer (score 1):

No CEX would ask you to make a deposit to prove your not laundering money. If your account is not KYC or AML compliant then large transfers can trigger holds until source of funds can be verified.

Based on what you've said - Coinw6 is a scam. If you or someone you know has funds held on there, report it to your local law enforcement.